# How can I access React/Redux current user outside of the render method?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I have a React/Redux/Firebase app and I need to check the current user's username before the render method so I know whether I need to go to the db and retrieve a different user.

However, for some reason I'm not clear on, I can't access `this.props.currentUser` outside of the render method. It returns null.

Basically, I want to access this inside of a function. My code looks like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
  var userURL = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');

  if(this.props.currentUser.username !== userURL) {
    this.getDbUser(userURL);
    console.log(userURL);
  }
}
```

I get an error

```
Cannot read property username of null
```

I can access that data fine in `render()`. Any idea how to fix this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: chances are your render method runs twice and on the second run, the user is defined. That's why it works in render

Comment: Thanks, render is in fact running twice, not sure why.  I'm calling a fetchUser method in the constructor so shouldn't it be available down the line?

Comment: not if it is async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Actually - `ComponentDidMount` is running before your asynchronous 'fetch' returns, therefore the currentUser will be `null`. Try changing `ComponentDidMount` to `ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and replace 'this.props' in your code with 'next.props'.

Everything inside of `ComponentWillReceiveProps` will run the once your props are updated with the 'fetched' user. For example:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  var userURL = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');

  if(nextProps.currentUser && nextProps.currentUser.username !== userURL) {
    this.getDbUser(userURL);
    console.log(userURL);
  }
}
```

The code above also includes `&&` in the IF so there will not be an error if the currentUser is `null`.

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops